# storing CSS and JS inside Android App which has webview like phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, css, caching, cordova

I need to store the css and js which will be used in an android app which uses webview, I dont want my app to request for css and js again and again on server and want to store locally on the phone, like phone gap does. Is there any documentation available for the same, how can i do it?

Comment: I store my html/js/css for webview in the assets folder

Comment: Why don't you just host it online and regulate caching using HTTP? See https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/caching -- That way you don't have to download the same content again and again.

Comment: @AlexvandenHoogen I have used bootstrap and some small plugins js in my app, I dont want to host online, storing on local app will reduce the response time, and only markup will be fetched from the server, everything else, javascript and css will be loaded locally. Http caching is good, but thats not what i am looking for..

Answer (score 0):

Deacoy is correct. You can download the actual css and js and store it in a folder inside your www folder created by Phonegap. Then, you just link to the local files instead of referring to outside hosted versions. If you store the css and js locally, it will be packaged with your app when you build your app with PhoneGap and the files will be loaded onto the phone with the install. Here is how our structure works:

```
www
   css (folder)
   js  (folder)
   img  (folder)
   res  (folder)
  cordova.js
  cordova_events.js
  cordova_plugins.js
  index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You can visit this site how to create cordova project from scratch.

http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/02/21/crud-operation-using-jquery-mobile-on-android-part-1/